# KDE: How to set shortcut for Pack Window -> Corner / Center

Tags: kde, window-management

I found the "Pack Window" shortcuts available in KDE and they work very well:

[image: Current shortcuts]

I would like to add shortcuts to move the window directly into the screen corners. Currently if I wanted to get my window into the bottom left corner I would have to do something like `Pack Window Left (Ctrl+Num4)` + `Pack Window Down (Ctrl+Num2)`

I would like to use a single shortcut, eg `Pack Window Bottom-Left (Ctrl+Num1)` to move my windows in this manner - and critically **without** changing the window size.

As well I would like to be able to center my window with a shortcut, eg `Pack Window Center (Ctrl+Num5)`, again **without** changing the window size - though a second shortcut that centered the window and set it to a predefined size would be very nice as well, so that I could have something like `Pack Window Center - Large (Ctrl+Shift+Num5)` for a 90% maximized window, centered.

I have found a couple of kwin scripts that approach what I want [here](https://github.com/KSmanis/kwin-move-window-to-center/blob/master/contents/code/main.js) and [here](https://github.com/piehei/kde-plasma-center-window/blob/master/contents/code/main.js), however I am a beginner regarding programming and this appears to be in JavaScript. I was hoping there was an easy GUI / template based approach to creating custom shortcuts that I had missed before I tried to dig into customizing or creating a script like these ones.

I am currently using Manjaro KDE edition.

Comment: Re. moving windows to the corners without resizing them, see https://askubuntu.com/a/1188195/248158. No idea about the other aspects.

Comment: I guess you could look at something `wmctrl` for placing windows in the center.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/104155/248158

Comment: @JusticeforMonica Your link shows using the KDE "Quick Tile" shortcuts, but unless I am missing something this shortcut **does resize the window**.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right! But I don't know if what you want is possible. I'll have to amend my answer there.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be more digestible than the KWin scripts you mentioned but I'm using a Bash script that relies on `xdotool` together with an `xbindkeys` configuration to map numpad keys.

The script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#
# Move a window to a certain location.
#
# Examples:
#   move-window.sh 'search --onlyvisible --name SpeedCrunch' top-right
#   move-window.sh getactivewindow bottom-left

set -euo pipefail

what=${1?What window would you like to move?}
where=${2?Where would you like to move your window to?}

# Determine the screen resolution
res=$(cat /sys/class/graphics/fb0/virtual_size)
screen_width=${res%,*} 
screen_height=${res#*,} 

# Determine the window size
window_id=$(xdotool $what)
eval $(xdotool $what getwindowgeometry --shell)

# Calculate the target location
case "$where" in
    top-left)       pos="0 0";;
    top-right)      pos="$(($screen_width-$WIDTH)) 0";;
    bottom-left)    pos="0 $(($screen_height-$HEIGHT))";;
    bottom-right)   pos="$(($screen_width-$WIDTH)) $(($screen_height-$HEIGHT))";;
    center)         pos="$(($screen_width/2-$WIDTH/2)) $(($screen_height/2-$HEIGHT/2))";;
    *)              pos="$where"
esac

# Move the window
xdotool windowmove $window_id $pos
```

Then in `~/.xbindkeysrc` I have the following:

```
# Win+Num7: Move active window to top left
"move-window.sh getactivewindow top-left"
    Mod4 + KP_Home

# Win+Num9: Move active window to top right
"move-window.sh getactivewindow top-right"
    Mod4 + KP_Prior

# Win+Num1: Move active window to bottom left
"move-window.sh getactivewindow bottom-left"
    Mod4 + KP_End

# Win+Num3: Move active window to bottom right
"move-window.sh getactivewindow bottom-right"
    Mod4 + KP_Next

# Win+Num5: Move active window to center
"move-window.sh getactivewindow center"
    Mod4 + KP_Begin
```

(Remember to (re)start `xbindkeys` after updating the config file.)

I haven't had a chance to test this on a multi-monitor setup and I don't expect this to work on Wayland but it works well enough on my current single-screen Debian bullseye + KDE setup.

Comment: Sadly doesn't seem to work for me on Manjaro KDE.

I will try and play with it when I have time. Thanks for the neat solution :)

Comment: Any chance it's a `$PATH` problem? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64356574/8268941).

Comment: For some reason xbindkeys wasn't working nicely for me. I ended up just making a custom shortcut in the KDE settings, which works. I use dual monitors though, so it always moves to the corner of my primary monitor, even if it is on the secondary - which you already said you hadn't tested so no surprise. It seems to work well otherwise though, nice job :)

Answer (score 0):

Notes:

- I don't have a numpad and so I'm using different shortcuts than what you use.
- You need to install `xdotool` from the repository. It can simulate key presses.
- This will probably not work in a Wayland session.

In *System Settings > Shortcuts > Global Shortcuts > Kwin*,

- I set <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> to "Pack Window Down" and
- <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to "Pack Window Right"

As you observed, these commands cannot be merged into one directly. You need to run them consecutively.

However, there's a workaround using `xdotool`.

- Open some window, not *konsole* just for simplicity, and size and place it somewhere but not in the bottom right corner.
- Open *konsole* and paste in the following code:
  `sleep 10s && xdotool key Super+Ctrl+Down && sleep 0.1 && xdotool key Super+Ctrl+Right`
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in *konsole* and then switch to the window you want to move into the right corner without it being resized.
- After 10s, the window in focus will be moved into the right corner without it being resized.

Assuming that works for you,

- open *System Settings > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts*
- Click on *Edit > New > Global Shortcut > Command/URL*
- In the left panel, provide a suitable name such as *Pack right bottom*
- In the right panel, enter a comment (optional)
- Next, for *Trigger*, click on the *Input* box and press the keys corresponding to the keyboard shortcut you'll use such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> or whatever is convenient and available.
- In the *Action* tab, paste in `xdotool key Super+Ctrl+Down && sleep 0.1 && xdotool key Super+Ctrl+Right`.
- Click *Apply* in the lower right-corner.

Now, whenever you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, the window in focus will be moved, without being resized, into the lower right corner of your screen.

Having a small *sleep* between the two `xdotool` commands is useful because sometimes `xdotool` can act up.

You'll need to repeat the whole process to pack windows in other corners.

---

I'm not addressing the other issue of centering windows with 90% of the screen size because that's more challenging.

But again, a sort of workaround is to have all windows appear initially centered. You can then move them wherever you like. To do so, open *System Settings > Window Management > Window Behavior > Advanced* and choose *Centered* under *Placement*.

Another route is to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>, choose *More Actions* and then *Special Window Settings* or *Special Application Settings* as required and then set up what you want in the *Size & Position* tab.